# Celery ignore_result not working properly

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have e Django application that calls periodically a serie of Celery tasks that use a redis backend to manage some stuff, I don't really need to store the results of all the tasks.
My redis gets quickly populated with entries called `celery-meta-data-some-random-id-string`, containing the task itself and its result.
I wanted to get rid of those so I added `'ignore_result' = True` to the tasks I didn't care about the result.

My task is defined as:

```
@shared_task(name='my.name', ignore_result = True)
def mytask(foo,bar):
    //do stuff
    return
```

I tried to add the default behaviour adding to my Django.settings `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True`
and from `celery.py` in my django application I loaded the settings like this

```
from django.conf import settings    
app = Celery('myapp')
app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')
```

Here is my setting.py

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://0.0.0.0/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', ] #'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml'
CELERY_BACKEND = 'redis://0.0.0.0/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://0.0.0.0/0'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Rome'
```

Using `Celery Flower` I can check the task configs, the `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT` variable is set to `True` for all of them, so i think the config is correct.

Is there something I'm completely missing?
I tried to work around this cleaning up the redis periodically but it would be more optimal to just not store the result at all.

Comment: possible relevant issue, even tho my tasks are called with sent_task https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5398

Comment: i dint look at your issue , but seeing first line of code `@shared_task(name='my.name','ignore_result' = True)`   i got a doubt , do you really pass `'ignore_result'`  with quotes ?? is it not just `ignore_result`  ??   i've never tried this , please let me know if both work the same way .

Comment: My mistake, I wrote it by memory and i made a mistake, it's fixed now.